# Компановка элементов в Layout

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Всем привет! У меня есть 12 разделов, по высоте(4 столбца) я разместил мои блоки с помощью 
атрибута weight,теперь мне нужно чтобы мой один блок занимал 1/3 layout по ширине,поскажите как лучше реализовать?

вот xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/avto" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/avto" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView5"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/avto" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

  </RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">


</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: покажите xml. "по фотографии" я не гадаю.

Comment: добавил , посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: `RelativeLayout` игнорирует `weight`. `weight` можно использовать только внутри `LinearLayout`

Comment: как мне внутри RelativeLayout разделить ширину на 3 части?

Comment: никак, он для этого не предназначен. Предназначен для этого `LinearLayout`

Comment: спасибо,получаеться для ширины я должен выбрать оптимальный фиксированный размер?

Comment: нет, для ширины надо положить элементы в LinearLayout, и задать им вес по 1

Comment: Как это, LinearLayout не работает же по горизонтали?

Comment: Работает. У него есть атрибут `orientation`, который определяет, по горизонтали он работает, или по вертикали

Comment: Все спасибо вдуплился,надо задать  android:orientation="horizontal"

Comment: Спасибо большое еще раз!